# It is true that $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1\leq p\leq\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, holder-inequality, schwartz-space

Remember that $\mathscr{S}'$ is the space of tempered distributions.

In a certain text they suggest that this statement is true, and that he uses Holder's inequality to prove it. ***The question is, how do I use it?***

Comment: Hint: The space of tempered distributions is the continuous dual space of the Schwarz space. If you write down the definition of a map being continuous, it should become clear that you need to show that a certain integral converges in some limit. At that point, you can use Holder's inequality to get the convergence.

Comment: I have the idea, but I still have a question: Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Then by Hölder’s inequality, with $q\in[1, \infty]$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, we have $$|u_f\varphi|=\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\varphi\right|\leq \|f\|_p\|\varphi\|_q.$$  I don't understand how to conclude.

Comment: Multiply and divide by a weight that is in $L^q$, then throw that into the $L^q$ norm. Sup out the weight times $\varphi$.

Comment: You need to show that if $\phi_n$ is a sequence of functions in the Schwarz space which converge to zero in the Schwarz space, then $|u_f \phi_n| \to 0.$ With your inequality, you just need to look at the definition of that space and show that convergence there implies that the $L^q$ norm tends to zero.